# iTextSharp "The document has no pages." error

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm creating a pdf file with an image. I'm getting the image, first saving it into the server, after creating an iTextSharp image with it;

```
iTextSharp.text.Image backgroundImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path);
```

On this line I'm getting an error "The document has no pages."

Here is the StackTrace:

```
   location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPages.WritePageTree()
   location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
   location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
   location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
   location: iTextSharp.text.DocWriter.Dispose()
   location: MyProject.Helpers.FileUploadHelper.SaveMarathonCertificateTemplate(HttpRequestBase Request, String _fileName, CertificateOrientation orientation) c:\MyProject\Helpers\FileUploadHelper.cs : line 68
   location: MyProject.Controllers.CertificateController.Add(Int32 marathonId, MarathonCertificate marathonCertificate) c:\MyProject\Controllers\CertificateController.cs: line 74
```

Yesterday code was working well, but weirdly today I'm getting this error. Here is my code:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(pdfFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
    {
        if (orientation == CertificateOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
            pdfDoc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
        using (var w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs))
        {
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.NewPage(); // add Page here

            iTextSharp.text.Image backgroundImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path);

            if (orientation == CertificateOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
            {
                backgroundImage.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(Config.PdfActualSizeHorizontal[0]);
                backgroundImage.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(Config.PdfActualSizeHorizontal[1]);
            }
            else if (orientation == CertificateOrientation.VERTICAL)
            {
                backgroundImage.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(Config.PdfActualSizeVertical[0]);
                backgroundImage.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(Config.PdfActualSizeVertical[1]);
            }
            backgroundImage.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            pdfDoc.Add(backgroundImage);

            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I cant't get the problem. Is there any solution?

> EDIT:

I added a line before getting Image instance

```
pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
```

After that the error becomes to this:

> System.ObjectDisposedException was caught   Message=Cannot access a
>   closed file.

New StackTrace:

```
location: System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
location: System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.WriteTo(Stream os)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Write(PdfIndirectObject indirect, Int32 refNumber, Int32 generation)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Add(PdfObject objecta, Int32 refNumber, Int32 generation, Boolean inObjStm)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Add(PdfObject objecta, PdfIndirectReference refa, Boolean inObjStm)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Add(PdfObject objecta, PdfIndirectReference refa)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddToBody(PdfObject objecta, PdfIndirectReference refa)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.Type1Font.WriteFont(PdfWriter writer, PdfIndirectReference piref, Object[] parms)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.FontDetails.WriteFont(PdfWriter writer)
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddSharedObjectsToBody()
location: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
location: iTextSharp.text.DocWriter.Dispose()
location: MyProject.Helpers.FileUploadHelper.SaveMarathonCertificateTemplate(HttpRequestBase Request, String _fileName, CertificateOrientation orientation) c:\MyProject\Helpers\FileUploadHelper.cs: line 70
location: MyProject.Controllers.CertificateController.Add(Int32 marathonId, MarathonCertificate marathonCertificate) c:\MyProject\Controllers\CertificateController.cs: line 74
```

Comment: The error you see merely is a side effect of the original error: Something goes wrong during `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path)`, hence an exception is thrown. It is not caught; thus, the closing of the `using` parameter occurs. As nothing has yet been added to the document, this closing fails and you only see the exception of that.

Comment: @mkl I just edited the question. Can you look at again?

Comment: The innermost `using` is wrong. This causes the `PdfWriter` to be closed first and only thereafter the `Document`. But the latter during closing requires the `PdfWriter` to still be open. If you look at the iTextSharp samples using an explicit `PdfWriter` (e.g. [HelloWorldDirect.cs](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter01/HelloWorldDirect.cs), you'll see that the `PdfWriter` is **not** created in a `using` clause.

Comment: I'm unable to get the posted code to throw that exception, is there more code involved that you haven't posted? For instance, do you have any `try/catch` that as @mkl said might be swallowing other errors?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Most likely the OP has an issue in `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path)` (Wrong path? Insufficient permissions?) making him produce empty PDFs which throws exceptions hiding the actual problem. And in this context the inappropriate `using` indeed is an issue. Without the exception disposal the line `pdfDoc.Close();` is reached and already correctly closes everything.

Comment: That's why I asked about the try/catch. I can get `GetInstance()` to throw a bunch of exceptions if I pass it values I know are bad

Comment: @ErdinçÖzdemir As your question has been *bumped to the homepage by Community♦,* are you still interested in solving this issue? Then please reply to the latest comments. Otherwise consider answering the question yourself (if you eventually solved the issue) or remove the question.

Comment: @ErdinçÖzdemir As your question has once again been bumped to the homepage by Community♦, are you still interested in solving this issue? Then please reply to the latest comments. Otherwise consider answering the question yourself (if you eventually solved the issue) or remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var path ="path of final pdf to save";
var imagePath="path of image that should be paste in final pdf file";
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
iTextSharp.text.Image myImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
myImage.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(document.PageSize.Height);
myImage.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(document.PageSize.Width);
myImage.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
document.Add(myImage);
document.Close();
```

Thats all.

Comment: Not using `using` is as inappropriate as over-using it.

Answer (score 0):

> Please verify the **HTML** does it contains the **Images** or Resource
>   files whose **URL** content does't exist ?  If Url path is missing
>   content (not opening) will cause such issue.